# First row in DataGrid missing

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to output a data grid that retrieves user data and puts it in a table. When I try to do this, I believe the first row is replaced by the column name, then an additional empty row gets added to the bottom. Can anyone see any discrepancies with this code chunk that may cause it to do this?

**Data Input:**

[image: Data Input]

**Output Given:**

[image: Output Given]

**Here's my code:**

```
Dim mRow As Integer = 0
Dim newpage As Boolean = True

With DataGridViewONE
    Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
    fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
    Dim y As Single = 770 'e.MarginBounds.Top
    Do While mRow < .RowCount
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)
        Dim x As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
        Dim h As Single = 1
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            Dim rc As RectangleF = New RectangleF(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Width, rc.Height)
            If mRow = 0 Then
                e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridViewONE.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, 
                                          .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
            Else
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridViewONE.Rows(cell.RowIndex).
                                          Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString(), 
                                          .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
            End If
            x += rc.Width
            h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
        Next
        newpage = False
        y += h
        mRow += 1
        If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
            e.HasMorePages = True
            mRow -= 1
            newpage = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Loop
    mRow = 0
End With
```

**EDIT**

I have found that the `ColumnIndex` replaces the first row. Technically, if `mRow` was set to -1, there wouldn't be an issue, but doing so gives the error that index cannot be a negative value.

```
If mRow = 0 Then
e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridViewONE.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, 
                                          .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
```

Replacing it with the Row `DrawString` would give the output I need but without the column headings

Comment: Firstly, a `DataGridView` is a `DataGridView`, not a `DataGrid`.  There are other controls that are called `DataGrid` so, instead of trying to save a few keystrokes, please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, which always includes using the correct names for things. I've been bitten by that far too many times.

Comment: As for the issue, have you debugged the code? It's not for us to read through the code in the hope that we see something. It's for you to step through the code as it's executing and then tell us where the discrepancy is.  Noone should post a question here without having debugged their code first. Once you've done that, if you still can't fix it yourself, you'll have far more relevant information to provide to us

Comment: By the way, you might like to [check this out](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?356115-DataGridPrinter-A-class-to-print-data-grid-in-a-nicely-formatted-way&highlight=datagridprinter). The original class is for printing a `DataGrid` (see what I mean?) but there is a similar class posted later on for printing a `DataGridView`. It might alleviate the need for any of your code.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Okay thank you, I'll take your comments into consideration. I just have no idea what's causing this issue and I'm determined to get rid of the problem as it's the last thing left to do! Apologies for the improper question

Comment: Hi ST - I cant see the top of your code, does it have `dim mRow as integer = 1` or `dim mRow as integer = 0` ? I'm guessing that you may need to also change the `Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)` to mRow -1. Edit your post and put the whole method in, then I'll have look over it. - _sometimes it just needs a second pair of eyes!_

Comment: @Chicken Updated now